# Why do the endless ask if you need their help?

Tags: breath-of-fire-4

During the game the party meet some of the endless (The dragons, e.g. Sea Dragon / Grass Dragon).

If you meet one of them and Ryu talks to them, they ask you, if you need their help. If you answer yes, Ryu can use their powers during the round based battles from time to time.

However, if you talk to an endless, he asks you "Do you need my help?". You can choose to say `Not now` so I was wondering, what, if any, impact does this have on the gameplay. Does anything change if you choose to not request the help?